# How to exclude null results from JPA query

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following named query in JPA:

```
<named-query name="getAllListingsWithId">
    <query>Select listing from ListedItemDetail listing where listing.listingId in :listingIds</query>
</named-query>
```

I then call run the code:

```
List<Integer> listingIds = new ArrayList<>(); // [23, 46, 72]
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("getAllListingsWithId");
query.setParameter("listingIds", listingIds);
List<ListedItemDetail> listings = query.getResultList(); // [Object23, null, Object72]
```

However, some of the 'listingIds' do not exist in the database and as such I get a resultList with some null values. How do I exclude null values efficiently? At the moment I use:

```
listings.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Can I do it in the namedQuery? I assume it will be faster.

Using MySQL, EclipseLink. Thanks.

ListedItemDetail:

```
public class ListedItemDetail extends Item{
    // Fields
}

public class Item{
    protected int listingId;
    // Other fields
}
```

orm.xml (xml defined entities):

```
<entity class="package.Item">
    <attributes>
        <id name="listingId">
        </id>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Comment: List<Integer> listingIds;

Comment: Are you saying that `listingIds.size==listsgs.size()`? That does not make sense. You result set will only contain records which match the query. i.e records which have `id` that is in `listingIds`. Also, you did not show is the query "getAllListingsWithIdExcludeNulls".

Comment: Hi I've edited to make a bit clearer. For each listingId that does not exist in the database (no row for that primary key), it creates a null element in the list (like shown in the comment in the question - listing 46 does not exist).

Comment: Can you post the code for `ListedItemDetail` entity? Also please post the generated SQL.

Comment: getAllListingsWithIdExcludeNulls was a test I did but didn't work, that was a copy paste error sorry, I've changed it to what it is.

Comment: I've added what I think is the relevant code for ListedItemDetail (an Item). Let me know what else you want (both classes are ~300 lines). Do you want me to turn on MySQL logging and look at the raw SQL queries being run against the database?

Comment: *Tiggles. Yes (with `<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/><property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>`). One quick test, please change the type of `listingId` to `Integer` (and maybe try to append `AND listing.listingId IS NOT NULL` to your query, although it does not make much sense).

Comment: One more thing, is `Item` a physical table (joined with `ListedItemDetail`)? Else declare it as a [mapped super class](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Example_mapped_superclass_XML).

Comment: try this query: `from ListedItemDetail l where l.listingId in :listingIds`... basically get rid of the `select listing`